# jQuery ui sortable toArray skips 1 item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to put all the li id's from the itemWrapper in one array after the order has been changed.

It does that but it loses one item all the time. It doesn't matter how much li's there are. Everytime it's missing one li id.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var result = "";
$("#itemWrapper").sortable({change: function(event, ui) {
    result = $("#itemWrapper").sortable("toArray");
}});
$(".colItem").disableSelection();

<ul id="itemWrapper" style="list-style-type:none;">
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_48_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309680939.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3768" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_50_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681037.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3765" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_58_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681326.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3768" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_51_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681056.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="11090" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_52_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681077.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3766" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_53_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681100.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3769" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_54_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681118.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="11092" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_55_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681135.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="11077" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_56_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681155.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3762" /></li> 
<li class="colItem ui-state-default" style="margin-right:-5px;" id="item_57_0_1"><img src="../images/items/1309681177.jpg" width="190" height="130" alt="3761" /></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't see anything like that - http://jsfiddle.net/csPv9/ Could you edit that fiddle to reproduce the error?

Comment: Confirmed it works on Dogbert's fiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the wrong event. If you use "stop" it works.  fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeYPJ/

```
$("#itemWrapper").sortable({stop: function(event, ui) {
    result = $("#itemWrapper").sortable("toArray");
     console.log(result.length);

}});
```

Thi is related to the fact, i think, that the change event is triggered while sorting: in that case it doesn't count the item you are sorting.